# No Layer Loaded: Please load layer to be georeferenced QGIS

Tags: qgis

I uploaded an image in JPG format, linked the image to the map through the georeferencer and OSM Standard, and when I clicked “Start georeferencing” I received the error

> No Layer Loaded: Please load layer to be georeferenced.

What is causing the error?

[image: Description]

Comment: Sometimes if you have closed Georeferencer and opened it again it still shows the previous image loaded as a background even if it hasn't actually been loaded for georeferencing. Save the GCP points you've created in the same location as your raster, and re-load the raster, and reload the GCP points you saved earlier (if it doesn't already auto load)